# Proving that addition in $\mathbb{N}$ is associative and commutative

Tags: proof-verification, induction, natural-numbers

> I would like to prove the associative and commutative property of the natural numbers by using Peanos axioms only. Did I justify every step in my proofs correctly?

---

Definition. $\forall n,m \in \mathbb{N}\ ,  \ n+m = \underbrace{s(s(...s}_\text{m} (n)...)) = s^{[m]}(n)\  $ where $s(n)$ is the successor function.

---

---

a) $\forall n,m,k \in \mathbb{N} , n+(m+k)=(n+m)+k$

Proof: Let $S\subset\mathbb{N}$ be the set for which a) holds.

1. Case $k=1 \ , \ \forall n,m \in \mathbb{N}$

$n +(m+1) =$ (definition of $+$) $ = s^{[m+1]}(n) = (*) = s(s^{[m]}(n)) = s(m + n) = (m+n) + 1$

I am not sure how to justify $(*)$. I have:

$s^{[m+1]}(n) = \underbrace{s(s(....s}_\text{m}(\underbrace{s}_\text{1}(n))...))=\underbrace{s}_\text{1}(\underbrace{s(s(...s}_\text{m}(n)...)))=s(s^{[m]}(n))$

The composition of functions is associative but am I implicitly assuming the commutative property of the natural numbers i.e. $m+1 = 1+m$ ?

2. Let $k\in S$ be arbitrary $\implies n+(m+k)=(n+m)+k$

$n+(m+(k+1))= $ (From 1. for $m+(k+1)$) =  $n +((m+k)+1) = $ (From 1. for $n+(t+1)$ and $t=m+k\in\mathbb{N}$) $=(n+t)+1 = (n + (m+k))+1 = (k\in S) = ((n+m)+k)+1=s^{[k]}(n+m)+1=s^{[k+1]}(n+m) = (n+m)+(k+1)$

From 1. we have $1\in S$ and from 2. we have $k\in S \implies s(k)=k+1\in S$ and by the axiom of mathematical induction it follows that $S = \mathbb{N}$.

---

---

b) $\forall n,m \in \mathbb{N}\ ,\ n+m=m+n$

Proof:

---

First we will show that $s(n) = s^{[n]}(1)$

$n=1 \implies s(1) = 1+1 = s^{[1]}(1)$

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be an arbitrary number for which the claim holds:

$s(n+1) = (n+1) + 1 = s(n) + 1 = s^{[n]}(1) + 1 = s^{[n+1]}(1)$

By the axiom of mathematical induction, the claim holds for all natural numbers.

---

Now let $S\subset\mathbb{N}$ be the set of all numbers for which the original claim holds.

1. Case $m=1$

$n+1 = s(n) = s^{[n]}(1) = 1 + n$

2. Let $m\in S$ be arbitrary $\implies n + m = m + n$

$n + (m+1) = s^{[m+1]}(n) = s(s^{[m]}(n)) =s(n+m) =$ ( $m\in S$ ) $= s(m+n) = s(s^{[n]}(m)) = s^{[n+1]}(m) = m + (n+1) =$ (Case 1.) $=m+(1+n)=$ (associative) $=(m+1)+n$.

From 1. we have $1\in S$ and from 2. we have $m\in S \implies s(m)=m+1\in S$ and by the axiom of mathematical induction it follows that $S = \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You'll have to clarify lines like "Let $S\subset\mathbb{N}$ be the set for which a) holds." I suspect you mean that you are looking at the $k$ which make it true foe all $m,n$ but since (a) has no free variables what you say is meaningless.

Comment: You'll find it much easier to root the inductions at $0$.

Comment: Well, the axiom of mathematical induction says that: If we have a set $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ for which : 1) $1\in S$ and 2) $n \in S \implies n+1 \in S$ then we can conclude that $S=\mathbb{N}$ so I thought that I have to show that for every $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $n + (m + 1) = (n+m) +1 $ i.e. $1\in S$ and then $n + (m + k) = (n+m) +k \implies n + (m + (k+1)) = (n+m) + (k+1)  $ i.e. 2) $n \in S \implies n+1 \in S$  and we conclude $ S = \mathbb{N}$. Regarding the second comment, the notes that I use state that $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$

Comment: OK, but as I said, that's not what you have written, is it?

Comment: I'd also recommend not using $\dots$ in such proofs/definitions. I think that's where you're getting confused. If you insist in excluding $0$ from $\mathbb{N}$ then the definition of $+$ in terms of $s$ is: $m+1=s(m)$, $m+s(n)=s(m+n)$. It's then pretty straightforward to prove associativity.

Comment: The definition was taken from here: https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~guljas/skripte/MATANALuR.pdf#page=11 (in Croatian) and the proof there goes as follows: Let $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. We have $n + (m +1) = s^{[m+1]}(n) = (*) = s(s(^{[m]}(n))) = s(n+m) = (n+m)+1$. Let's assume that for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ the following holds: $n+(m+k) = (n+m)+k$. Then we have $n+ (m+ (k+ 1)) =n+ ((m+k) + 1) =(n+ (m+k)) + 1 = ((n+m) +k) + 1 = (n+m) + (k+ 1)$. From the axiom of mathematical induction the claim follows. Only $(*)$ is bothering me.

Comment: I'm sorry, it just seems to me not to be a good enough definition as it leads to exactly this doubt. I think you are right when you say you've used $m+1=1+m$ at $(*)$; the problem is that the Peano arithmetic is escaping into the mathematical language describing it. In most standard formulations one proves associativity, then $1+m=m+1$ then full commutativity.

Comment: I thought about it a little more and I think that I got it. A composition of functions works from the inside to the outside so $s^{[m+1]}(n) = s(s^{[m]}(n))$ doesn't mean that we assumed $m+1 = 1+m$. My interpretation of the right side of the equation was wrong. We don't apply the successor function $1+m$ times but actually $m+1$ times (just like the left side of the equation) because the composition of functions works like that (firstly, the successor function will be applied m times and then one more time which is $m+1$ and not $1+m$ times).

Comment: I am not convinced by any of this. Peano arithmetic is about an abstract set which you call $\mathbb{N}$. In it live things like $m$. But when you write $s^{[m]}(n)$ the $m$ is no longer an element of $\mathbb{N}$, it is - well ,what is it? - perhaps something in the mathematical language we use to talk about $\mathbb{N}$. For sure it is not the same $m$. That's why the definition you are using is defective. At this primitive level you can't use the elements of $\mathbb{N}$ as words in mathematical english, trying to explain what a $\dots$ means.